# Latency SLO calculation of requests

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana, promql

I need to calculate and plot latency SLO graph on prometheus by the histogram time-series, but I've been unsuccessful to display a histogram in grafana.
A sample metric would be the request time of an nginx.

suppose if i have a histogram bucket like this,

```
nginx_request_time_bucket(le=1) 1,
nginx_request_time_bucket(le=10) 2,
nginx_request_time_bucket(le=60) 2,
nginx_request_time_bucket(le=+inf) 5
```

I use this below expression to validate latency SLO . This expression returns the percentage of  requests within 10s :

```
sum(rate(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="10"}[$__range])) / sum(rate(nginx_request_time_count[$__range]))
```

Now how can i find the percentage of requests within 10s to 60s ? How can I calculate it?

Is the below expression correct??

```
(
  sum(rate(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="10"}[$__range]))
+
  sum(rate(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="60"}[$__range]))
) / 2 / sum(rate(nginx_request_time_count[$__range]))
```

Any help here is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All the `{le="10"}` requests are also included in `{le="60"}` (and in all the bigger buckets), so in order to know the amount of requests between them you just have to subtract the rates, so something like:

```
(
  sum(rate(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="60"}[$__range]))
   - 
  sum(rate(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="10"}[$__range]))
)
/ sum(rate(nginx_request_time_count[$__range]))
```

should work.

Comment: Many thanks .. Your solution makes sense.. If this is the solution, then what is this all about which they have mentioned in prometheus docs. https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/#apdex-score

Answer (score 1):

If you need to plot an SLI / SLO graph on the share of requests with durations not exceeding some threshold, based on [Prometheus histogram](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#histogram), then Prometheus doesn't provide the needed functionality yet.

It is possible to calculate the share of requests not exceeding pre-defined thresholds, which are equal to histogram boundaries defined via `le` label as shown in another answer:

```
sum(increase(nginx_request_time_bucket{le="10"}[1h]))
  /
sum(increase(nginx_request_time_bucket_count[1h]))
```

The query calculates the share (in the range `[0 .. 1]`) of requests that didn't exceed 10 seconds during the last hour.

An estimated share of requests for arbitrary threshold can be calculated when using an [alternative Prometheus-like system I work on](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics), with the following MetricsQL query:

```
histogram_share(10, sum(increase(nginx_request_time_bucket[1h])) by (le))
```

This query calculates an estimated share of requests not exceeding 10 seconds during the last hour. See [histogram_share() docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_share).

P.S. Prometheus provides [histogram_fraction](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#histogram_fraction) function, which can be used for SLI / SLO calculations similar to the above calculations. Unfortunately, this function doesn't work with traditional Prometheus histograms - it works only with experimental [native histograms](https://promcon.io/2022-munich/talks/native-histograms-in-prometheus/).